# SSMS renaming Keys also renames Clustered index to same name

Tags: sql-server, ssms

As the title states really.

An example of this is;

I set the primary key for a table which is a composite key made from multiple columns.
I then rename the key name in the Keys folder to;

```
PK_tblname_column1_column2
```

I then create a clustered index;

```
Create CLUSTERED INDEX C_U_tblname_column1_column2 ON tblname (Column1 ADC, Column2 ASC);
```

When I go to refresh the database, both of the names change to either PK or C_U so I get;

```
Keys - 
      PK_tblname_Column1_Column2
Indexes -
      PK_tblname_Column1_Column2 (Clustered)
```

OR

```
Keys - 
      C_U_tblname_Column1_Column2
Indexes -
      C_U_tblname_Column1_Column2 (Clustered)
```

Then, when I go to rename the Keys property back to `PK_tblname_Column1_Column2`, it automatically changes the Index property to `PK_tblname_Column1_Column2 (Clustered)` too.

If I then proceed to rename the Index property back to `C_U_tblname_Column1_Column2 (Clustered)`. It saves. However, when I refresh the database again, it reverses back to either being named PK for both or C_U for both.

Anyone know why this happens? Most of my clustered indexes just use the primary key columns as the clustered index but this also occurs on indexes that have more than the primary key columns included.

Comment: If the Primary Key is Clustered then the Primary Key and the Clustered Index are the **same thing**; renaming the Index is also renaming the Key as they are the same.

Comment: @Larnu ahh I see thanks for explaining. I just assumed you could still have separate naming conventions for both the Primary key and the Clustered Index.

Comment: @Larnu, just wondering. If this is the case, when I have a clustered primary key,. Would I need to create a clustered index or is it automatically created when you create a clustered primary key?

Comment: A PK is by default clustered unless specified otherwise (you can have a PK that is non-clustered).

Comment: You can have only ONE clustered index. Do not assume it must be the primary key. Make the choice of clustered index an active and thoughtful process. Searching on that topic will find guidance for making that choice.